# Fetch entity with association using one query in hibernate search

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm pretty new to Hibernate Search project,so any advices will be appriciated. Assume I have an entity **Foo** and entity **Bar** connected with one-to-many relationship. Mapping may look as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="foos")
@Indexed
public class Foo {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @IndexedEmbedded
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "bar_id")
  private Bar bar;

  //getters, setters, etc.

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "bars")
public class Bar {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="bar")
  private Set<Foo> fooSet;

  //getters, setters, etc.

}
```

Now when I try to query Foo table using lucene/hibernate search dsl, I get the result query like this:

```
select this_ from foos this_ where this_.id in (id collection fetched from lucene)
```

So my **Bar** entity was proxied by hibernate because of lazy fetch type. My question is there a way to fetch **Foo** and **Bar** using one query (using join or whatever)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I've found a solution. We need to use method **setCriteriaQuery(Criteria)** from [FullTextQuery](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.5/api/org/hibernate/search/jpa/FullTextQuery.html) interface. From javadoc:

> Defines the Database Query used to load the Lucene results. Useful to load a given object graph by refining the fetch modes No projection (criteria.setProjection() ) allowed, the root entity must be the only returned type No where restriction can be defined either

So, solution looks like this:

```
FullTextQuery myQuery = ... //setup my lucene query here
Criteria fetchAssociationCriteria = session.createCriteria(Foo.class);
fetchAssociationCriteria.setFetchMode("bar", FetchMode.JOIN);
List<Foo> foos = myQuery.setCriteriaQuery(fetchAssociationCriteria).getResultList();
```

Which produces query like:

```
select (foo and bar attributes) from foos this_ left outer join bar bars2_ where this.id in (id collection fetched from lucene)
```

**Hint for JPA users**:

FullTextQuery interface supports JPA but you need to pass Hibernate's criteria query into **setCriteriaQuery()** method. To get Hibernate's session use EntityManager's unwrap method.

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
```

Comment: Very very good answer! What is interesting hibernate is getting what he can from indexes (Id's) and on Id's he fetch associations what You define. Interesting.

Comment: I was able to use setCriteriaQuery in hibernate 4, but in hibernate 5 criteria has been deprecated. 
I don't really know how to combine full text query and the setFetchMode

Comment: I could not see any method in Hibernate Search 6.0.0.Beta2 for achieving the same.

Comment: This title of this section in the documentation for Hibernate Search 6 sounds promising: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#_entity_graph